# URL patterns and how to use them for external link django

Tags: python, django, reddit

Inexperienced with Django, but I have been playing with the Reddit API and it is easy and fun to use. I think I don't understanding something fundamental about template tags and urls in Django. All I really want to do is to have an href link to 'http://redd.it/' with the reddit id for the post after the slash.

My model is:

```
class Reddit_Model(models.Model):
    reddit_title = models.CharField(max_length=500,default='')
    reddit_score = models.CharField(max_length=20,default='')
    reddit_id = models.CharField(max_length=20,default='')
    reddit_url=models.URLField(blank=True,max_length=500)
```

And in the template if I use:

```
<a href="{{ entry.reddit_url }}">{{ entry.reddit_url }}</a>
```

I connect to the external URL as expected.

However that  URL can be the external URL that someone put in their post, so if I want to go back to the persons post (for example a post that has a reddit_id of ge2oap) and I type into the browser http://redd.it/ge20ap it will go to the post as desired. However when I try to construct a template tag I run into problems.
if I use

```
<a href="{{http://redd.it/{{entry.reddit_id}}}">http://redd.it/{{ entry.reddit_id }}</a>
```

and got

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/mainapp/'http://redd.it'%20ge2oap
```

which I think makes sense, so I tried various URL template tag patterns

```
<a href="{% url 'http://redd.it/' entry.reddit_id %}">http://redd.it/{{ entry.reddit_id }}</a>
```

none of which work. I suppose I could create another field in the model. 
I looked at the redirect functions and the get_absolute_URL() in the docs, but didn't see how they could be used in this situation, so I suspect I am missing something obvious. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<a href="{{http://redd.it/{{entry.reddit_id}}}">http://redd.it/{{ entry.reddit_id }}</a>
```

should be

```
<a href="http://redd.it/{{entry.reddit_id}}">http://redd.it/{{ entry.reddit_id }}</a>
```

as the first part of the href isn't a template variable. Note that you can't nest braces like that anyway.

Comment: Thanks, I had tried that, and I think the browser wasn't refreshing or something, so I tried it with yours and it didn't work, but when I went and inspected the link, it looked right and clicked it in chrome developer and it went to the right page, then after that it seems like things work fine.